# Vue.js Vite Build Error with <video><source> tags

Tags: vue.js, rollupjs, vite

I'm working on a Vue 3 app and am trying to swap out a static image for a video and it's throwing a

```
[vite] Build errored out.
Error: Unexpected character '' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript) at error (/myapp/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:5275:30)
...
```

This builds (not that you'd use an image but just to show):

```html
<video class="w-2/3 xs:w-full" controls="controls" name="Video Name">
     <source src="/images/my_image.png">
</video>
```

This does not:

```html
<video class="w-2/3 xs:w-full" controls="controls" name="Video Name">
     <source src="/images/my_movie.mov">
</video>
```

I'm new to Vite and am trying to understand why it seems to be wanting to import the video from the HTML tag.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by @adain, `.mov` files are not in the [default list of asset types to exclude from the transform pipeline used in the build](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/e87ae41/packages/vite/src/node/constants.ts#L58).

The solution is to configure [`assetsInclude`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#assetsinclude) to add `.mov` files to that list:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.mov'],
  ⋮
})
```

<del>An alternative workaround is to [bind](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-bind) a literal string:</del> *(not necessary with the `assetsInclude` configuration above)*

```html
<video class="w-2/3 xs:w-full" controls="controls" name="Video Name">
  <!-- BEFORE -->
  <!--<source src="/images/my_movie.mov">-->

  <source :src="`/images/my_movie.mov`">
</video>
```

Comment: That did the trick for me. Thanks so much for the help... saved hours of time.

Answer (score 1):

Vite seem can not resolve `.mov` video files. Read the document, set `assetsInclude` , build successed.

```
export default defineConfig({
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.mov'],
  ...
})
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for pointing us in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Add poster="/images/my_image.png" to the video tag. Like this;

<video poster=“/images/my_image.png” …

Otherwise, you can’t put an image into the source tag.

Comment: Sorry, my example was pretty lousy. Using the .png file was just to illustrate that doing the build would work if I swapped out the .mov for an image file in the <source> tag (even though you wouldn't do that) but using a .mov or .mp4 it does not and I instead get the error above. You are right, that the <video> tag is actually replacing an <img> tag in the code but it won't compile and instead is throwing the error.